# Replace only differences in DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, animation, rendering, transition

I have a data-model and many render-methods that render the views to the DOM. Currently, when the data changes I re-render the DOM with the corresponding method. It works just fine. Now what I want is that I don't re-render the whole DOM but compare the current DOM to the output of the render-method and only replace the differences! Why I need that? I want css-transitions to make the animation smooth so I can't replace the whole DOM but only the differences.

I can't wait for your opinions to make this work without checking for specific changes. I want to make it abstract.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did it the hard way... if anybody has a more elegant solution, I would be glad if he shared it! :-)

```
function applyChanges(source, destination) {

    var srcAttributes = source[0].attributes;
    var dstAttributes = destination[0].attributes;

    for (var i = 0; i < dstAttributes.length; i++) {
        if (typeof srcAttributes[dstAttributes[i].nodeName] === "undefined") {
            destination.removeAttr(dstAttributes[i].nodeName);
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < srcAttributes.length; i++) {
        if (typeof dstAttributes[srcAttributes[i].nodeName] === "undefined" || srcAttributes[srcAttributes[i].nodeName].nodeValue != dstAttributes[srcAttributes[i].nodeName].nodeValue) {
            $(destination).attr(srcAttributes[i].nodeName, srcAttributes[i].nodeValue);
        }
    }

    if (destination[0].children.length != source[0].children.length) {
        destination.html(source.html());
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < source[0].children.length; i++) {
        var srcChild = source[0].children[i];
        var dstChild = destination[0].children[i];

        if ($(srcChild).outerHtml() != $(dstChild).outerHtml()) {
            applyChanges($(srcChild), $(dstChild));
        }
    }

    if (destination.html() != source.html()) {
        destination.html(source.html());
    }
}
```